# Add multiple statements to IF/OR

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am looking to add a formula which states multiple ifs into one equation (not the best at this)
The equations are below, which are in cell H2

```
DES = EQ
DSW = OTC
DRS = OTC
342 = FX
HFX = FX
0C8 = ETD
109 = SS
```

Wanted to simply as much as possible so that it starts off similar to the below, just wasn't sure how to add the rest.

Started with

```
=IF(H2="DES","EQ"
```

Comment: Just use a lookup table... much easier to edit in the future, and much easier formula to write.

Comment: Don't use a massive If/else/if/else... formula.  This type of thing is precisely what the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) is designed to do.

Comment: True, although if you have Excel 2019 or better you can also use IFS.

Comment: @TomSharpe I would hard code the values in an INDEX/MATCH or CHOOSE/MATCH if that is what is wanted as it will be less typing and only one cell reference, and it will work in almost all versions.

Comment: Yes, you're right, certainly if you have as many as 7 values to compare, maybe if you only had 3 or 4 it wouldn't be worth it. But then you still might want to add more in the future...